# Provide public assets through vuejs npm package

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, rollupjs

I have a vue plugin bundle with [bili](https://bili.egoist.sh/).

This plugin use various public assets for 3d rendering and tensorflow like .glb file or .bin file.

Any way to provide public folder trough a npm package ?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm looking to do the same. Thanks.